# extract 3D matrix's columns based on "surface" values - vectorization

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have an NxMxK matrix `A`

```
A = [1 2 1; 1 1 2];
A = cat(3, A, [3 3 3; 3 3 3])
```

> A(:,:,1) =
>
> ```
>  1     2     1
>  1     1     2
> ```
>
> A(:,:,2) =
>
> ```
>  3     3     3
>  3     3     3
> ```

and I want to create a YxK 2D matrix `B` where K is the number of elements of `A(:,:,1)==2`:

```
k=0;
for ii=1:size(A,1)
   for jj=1:size(A,2)
      if A(ii,jj)==2
         k=k+1;
         B(k,:) = A(ii,jj,:);
      end
   end
end
```

Is there a way of vectorizing this code?

My attempt was to find the indices of `A(:,:,1)==2` and then try to select the whole column but I do not know how to do it:

```
inds = find(A(:,:,1)==2)
B = A(inds,:) %this line does not make sense
```

**EDIT**
Preallocating `B` helps:

```
inds=find(A(:,:,1)==2);
B=NaN(numel(inds),size(A,3));

k=0;
for ii=1:size(A,1)
   for jj=1:size(A,2)
      if A(ii,jj)==2
         k=k+1;
         B(k,:) = squeeze(A(ii,jj,:));
      end
   end
end
```

But still not vectorized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first attempt at vectorization is almost right. Just don't use `find`, but use the logical matrix for indexing.

```
inds = A(:,:,1)==2;
```

The `inds` matrix is 2D, not 3D, so we use `repmat` to repeat its values along the 3rd dimension:

```
K = size(A,3);
inds = repmat(inds,1,1,K);  % or simply cat(3,inds,inds) if K==2
B = A(inds);
```

The result is a column vector of size `Y*K`, not a matrix of size `Y`x`K`, we can use `reshape` to fix that:

```
B = reshape(B,[],K);
```

I guess this answer is similar to [Anthony's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51317097/7328782), except the indexing and the reshaping are reversed. I didn't really notice the similarity until after I wrote it down. I guess also Anthony's is a little shorter. :/

Answer (score 3):

You can `reshape` matrix `A` to a (N*M)xK 2D matrix.

```
A = [1 2 1; 1 1 2];
A = cat(3, A, [3 3 3; 3 3 3]);

A_ = reshape(A,numel(A(:,:,1)),size(A,3));
B = A_(A_(:,1)==2,:);
```

Comment: `reshape` allows an empty array as one of the size arguments, so you don't need to compute that one: `A_ = reshape(A,[],size(A,3));`. Nice answer!